# Why i am getting different tuning parameters each run when using GridSearchCV with random forest regressor?

Tags: python, regression, random-forest, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I am trying to get best parameters for Random forest regressor using GridSearchCV,, but each time i run the code i got different sets of best parameters.

I tried to add random_state=42 to GridSearchCV, but it seems not acceptable.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


df = pd.read_excel (r'Data_sets.xlsx',sheet_name="Set1")
X = np.transpose([df['b']])
y = np.array(df['d'])


def evaluate(model, test_features, test_labels):
    predictions = model.predict(test_features)
    errors = abs(predictions - test_labels)
    mape = 100 * np.mean(errors / test_labels)
    accuracy = 100 - mape
    print('Model Performance')
    print('Average Error: {:0.4f} degrees.'.format(np.mean(errors))) #Mean Absolute Error
    print('Accuracy = {:0.2f}%.'.format(accuracy))

    return accuracy

def rfr_model(X, y):
    # Split the data into training and testing sets
    train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)

    # Perform Grid-Search
    rf_random = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=RandomForestRegressor(),
    param_grid={
        'max_depth': (10,30,50,80,100,150,200,250,300),
        'n_estimators': (10, 50, 100,200,300,400,500,1000),
    },
    cv=10, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', verbose=0,n_jobs=-1)

    #fit the model
    rf_random.fit(train_features, train_labels)
    best_random = rf_random.best_estimator_
    print(best_random)
    random_accuracy = evaluate(best_random, test_features, test_labels)
    print(random_accuracy)


rfr_model(X, y)
```

I would like to know why i got different n_estimators and max_depth each time i run the code. Am i having mistakes that cause the problem?. I hope someone who can guide me as this is the first time i deal with regression.

Comment: Try adding `import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)` at the very top of the code, and remove the other import of numpy. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks. it does not help as the problem still the same.

Comment: You can try setting the random_state like this: `estimator=RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)` (as per this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39727/using-gridsearchcv-and-a-random-forest-regressor-with-the-same-parameters-gives)). This should not matter though if you set it at the top of the code, because if that parameter to RFR is omitted or None, the random state instance from numpy will be used.

Comment: May be different parameter combination have same performance. Can you check if they are same. And does it have something to do with n_jobs, can you try only one job?

Comment: Thanks vpekar, it works now by always returning the same results.